# Remove older map - Open Layers 3

Tags: dictionary, openlayers-3, destroy

I would like to change the icons features on a map
My idea was to delete the old map and generate a new one

My map:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  renderer: 'canvas',
  target: 'mapOl',      
  layers: [ignLayer, vectorLayer],
  overlays: [overlayPopup],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 9,
    maxZoom: 13, //Limit zoom levels
    minZoom: 7 
  })
});
```

Removal:

```
$("#mapOl").empty();
```

It generate a new map with the right icons feature but the first map is still there !

How should I do, delete the first card or try to change the icons ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ! I found a solution

First of all, I create **only once** instance of my map then I assign it a reference in jQuery with the function **.data ()**.

Then when I want to "reload" my map (with icons features), I check **reference of map is null**, if it null so declare my map and everything that goes with it (vectorLayers, others layers...), else I delete old vectorLayer (iconFeatures) of my map with his reference and affect new vectorLayer.

Here is all the code:

```
function displayMap(communesNbResults)
{
  /**
   * Elements that make up the popup.
   */
  var container = document.getElementById('popup');
  var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
  var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

//Create icons features by searching his geocode (long, lat)
 let vectorSource = createIconsFeature(communesNbResults);

//create the style
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    opacity: 1,
    src: "data:image/png;base64,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"
  }))
});

//add the feature vector to the layer vector, and apply a style to whole layer
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: iconStyle
});

//Check if map not already exist
if($('#mapOl').data('map') == null)
{
  var center = ol.proj.transform([-2.811813, 48.557159], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

  //Create all layers
  //Carte IGN
  let ignLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
      preload: Infinity,
      source : new ol.source.WMTS({
          url: "https://wxs.ign.fr/KEY/geoportail/wmts",
          layer: "GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.MAPS",
          matrixSet: "PM",
          format: "image/jpeg",
          style: "normal",
          tileGrid : new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
              origin: [-20037508,20037508],
              // topLeftCorner
              resolutions: resolutions, // résolutions
              matrixIds: ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19"] // ids des TileMatrix                      // ids des TileMatrix
          })
      }),
  });

  /**
   * Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map.
   */
  var overlayPopup = new ol.Overlay(/** @type {olx.OverlayOptions} */ ({
    element: container,
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250
    }
  }));

  var map = new ol.Map({
    renderer: 'canvas',
    target: 'mapOl',      
    layers: [ignLayer, vectorLayer],
    overlays: [overlayPopup],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: center,
      zoom: 9,
      maxZoom: 13, //Limit zoom levels
      minZoom: 7 
    })
  });
  //Set reference for jQuery
  $('#mapOl').data('map', map);
  $('#mapOl').data('vectorLayer', vectorLayer);

  //Create and layerSwitcher at map
  var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
    // paramétrage de l'affichage de la couche OSM
    layers : [{
        layer: ignLayer,
        config: {
            title: "Carte IGN",
            description: "Carte topographique IGN"
        }
    }],
  });
  //Set reference for layerSwitcher
  $('#mapOl').data('layerSwitcher', layerSwitcher);

  //Add layerSwitcher at map
  map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
  //Remove layer icons (markers) of layerSwitcher !
  layerSwitcher.removeLayer(vectorLayer);

  //Listener 
  /**
    * Add a click handler to the map to render the popup.
    */
  map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature) {
          return feature;
        });

      //Si clique sur un marker ! 
      if (feature) {
        var coordinate = evt.coordinate;

        //Get infos to display
        let infos = feature['infos'][0];
        let hrefId = "map_" + infos['commune'];

        content.innerHTML = 'Infos';

        //Add "event listener" to retrieve all actesIndividus for this commune
        $(content).on('click', $('a#'+hrefId), function() {
            //Find tag <a>
            let aId = $(this).find( "a" ).prop('id');
            //Split to get Commune
            let commune = aId.split('_')[1];

            //Close map modal
            $('#modalcarte').modal('hide');

            //Call method to retrieve all actesIndividus (method: gene)
            mapToGene(commune);
        });

        //Show popup
        $(container).show();
        overlayPopup.setPosition(coordinate);
      }
  });

  /**
   * Add a click handler to hide the popup.
   * @return {boolean} Don't follow the href.
   */
  closer.onclick =  function() {
    overlayPopup.setPosition(undefined);
    closer.blur();
    return false;
  };
}
else //Change only vectorLayer (markers)
{
  let map = $('#mapOl').data('map');
  let oldVectorLayer = $('#mapOl').data('vectorLayer');
  //Set reference for new vectorLayer (for future map)
  $('#mapOl').data('vectorLayer', vectorLayer);

  let layerSwitcher = $('#mapOl').data('layerSwitcher');

  //Remove old and add new vectorLayer
  map.removeLayer(oldVectorLayer);
  map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

  //Remove layer icons (markers) of layerSwitcher !
  layerSwitcher.removeLayer(vectorLayer);
}
```

}